# How to get number of div left after deleting?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my HTML there are eight `div`. I was able to get the number of the div using jQuery and insert it into the `.num div` element.

However when I delete one of the `div` by clicking the delete button, the number of divs in the `span` retrieved through jQuery won't update to the current number of divs remaining. It will still show `8`.

How can I get the current number of `div` elements left in the DOM immediately after clicking the button?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  if ($(".delete div").length > 0) {
    $(".num span").html($(".delete div").length);
  }
}, 100);

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".delete div:last-child").remove();
})
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```
<div class="delete">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
  <div class="div7">7</div>
  <div class="div8">8</div>
</div>

<div class="num">Number of div: <span>0</span></div><br>
<button>delete</button>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're using `setTimeout()`, which only runs once after the specified delay.

For the pattern you're using to work you need to use `setInterval()` instead, which will run repeatedly at the set delay:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  if ($(".delete div").length > 0) {
    $(".num span").html($(".delete div").length);
  }
}, 100);

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".delete div:last-child").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delete">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
  <div class="div7">7</div>
  <div class="div8">8</div>
</div>

<div class="num">Number of div: <span>0</span></div><br>
<button>delete</button>
```

**However**, using a timer for this is not ideal. As the number of `div` elements is only affected when the button is clicked, just update the `.num span` element  in that event handler:

```js
var $span = $(".num span").html($(".delete div").length);

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".delete div:last-child").remove();
  $span.html($(".delete div").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delete">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
  <div class="div7">7</div>
  <div class="div8">8</div>
</div>

<div class="num">Number of div: <span>0</span></div><br>
<button>delete</button>
```